# What games does Faye play when she loses all of her money?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

Faye is perpetually losing all of her money gambling.  We know she's addicted to gambling in general, but is there anything in specific that we know she tends to love playing (but always loses) at?

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting though that the picture above shows her winning against Jet. This is only because she's cheating on the game and Spike calls her out on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was never explicitly stated in the anime, but in her first appearance, she was playing Blackjack.

Not sure how credible [this link](http://www.angelfire.com/art2/bluprint/anime/cowboy_bebop/faye.htm) is but it does backup what card terms follow her..

> ...Faye is really good at gambling, especially where poker or blackjack is involved because she cheats ...

Also her [aliases](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Faye_Valentine) are **Poker Alice** and **Queen Of Hearts**. It can probably be deduced from that with any words she *might* have used in any games she played in the anime. So its possibly Poker and or Blackjack.